# The glad header can't be located when compiling

Tags: c++, mingw, glfw, glad

I'm attempting to create a window in GLFW and everything was working as expected until after I reset my PC (the reason for the reset is unrelated to this problem). I had my project stored on a separate drive so it was unmodified and I re-installed minGW and GLFW. But now, Everytime I tried to compile my project it returns: `fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory` for both main.cpp and glad.c, despite it being in the folder specified.

I compiled with `g++ -o windows.exe main.cpp glad.c -Linclude -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lgdi32`.

Main.cpp:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    }
}

int main() {
    //initializes glfw
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    
    //tells GLFW that this is opengl 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    
    //makes the window
    GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 1000, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    //error checks the window
    if (!window) {
        return -1;
    }

    //makes the context in the current window
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    //loads glad
    gladLoadGL();

    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

I've tried changing the include preprocessor directive to `#include "include/glad/glad.h"`, I've tried moving all the subfolders of the include folder into the main project folder, I've tried switching the quotations to angle brackets and I've tried re-installing minGW and GLFW altogether.
Could I have possibly installed minGW and GLFW incorrectly? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are using `-L` switch to specify include path which is incorrect. You should use `-I` switch to specify the include path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure non of the paths in use have spacial characters (like spaces) in them. This includes the location of: the compiler tool (gcc.exe), your sources, sources of dependencies used (glad in your case).

Next it's best to build your dependencies seperately (in case of glad you can use `cmake -GNinja` to configure it and then `ninja` to build it).

Finally I recommend to split the compiler and linker steps in seperate commands. This would look like something like this:

```bash
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp -Iglad/include
g++ -o windows.exe main.o -Lglad/lib -lglad -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lgdi32
```

In the above example you can replace `glad/` with an absolute path if needed.

In your question you didn't specify the `-I` compiler flag to tell the compiler where to find the header file(s) and you used `-L` put pointed it to the `include` folder instead of `lib` where libraries usually are located.

Note that the `-l` file takes the library name as parameter, which is the part of the the library file name without the leading `lib` and trailing `.a` (or `.dll.a` for shared libraries).